# same session, different domains, set session id

Tags: php, session, cookies, symfony1, cross-domain

I have a couple of domains which i want to shere sessions.
I have created a method like this:

The user login is done in a central place and the sessions are saved in the database.

Lets say the user A wants to go to abc.com domain. My app redirects it to the main authentication domain where he logs in.
After login is generated an auth token which is saved in a field in the sessions table and it is pass back to the abc.com application.

There I use the auth_token to get the session_id from the database and to set the session_id of abc.com the same.

The problem is that it allways creates a new session.

This is my code of the abc.com

```
$sessionId = // get from the database using the auth_token.
 /* CLOSE PREVIOUS SESSION */
            session_destroy();

// sets the new id.  
            session_id($sessionId);

            /** start new session * */
            session_start();
```

What i am missing?.
I am using php with Symfony framework. Dont know if it´s related with symfony session handling.

Comment: are the domains on the same server?  Here's a link that has an example of exactly what you want to do. Looks like your doing it right, so I would say it's possible your framework is stopping it.  http://www.gonnalearn.com/2008/04/10/sharing-session-data-across-domains-with-php/

Comment: What version of symfony are you using? Are the 2 domains 2 applications within 1 symfony install, or are their systems separate?

Comment: One of the domains is running Symfony 1.4 and the other Symfony 1.3. And yes the domains are in the same server.

Comment: @brpaz can you please add a full source code to answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. I solved my problem.
I had to delete the old session cookie after calling session_destroy().

Here is my full code if someone is interested:

```
$sessionId =  // get session id from  the database using the auth_token
session_destroy();

$this->getResponse()->setCookie('mycookie',null,time()-3600);

session_id($sessionId);

/** start new session * */

session_start();

$this->getResponse()->setCookie('mycookie', $sessionId,null,null,'mydomain');
```

Thanks everyone for the help.